# Quote process in Salesforce1

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, quote

I want to implement Sales process in Salesforce 1 i.e. creating opportunity then quote-lineitems, adding products,quantity,price and genarating PDF and then at-last sending emails.

As we cant create new quotes from Salesforce 1 as per spring 2014 release.We can view but cant create quote,quotelineitems.Please visit this link

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000188500&language=en_US

Replicating creating quotes in custom functionality looks quite complicated. As pricebook,products,quotelineitems standard functionality in Salesforce .I will have to create everything.

Can someone suggest me a possible solution or an appexchange app or an unmanaged app or any suggestion....It will be really helpful to me..

Thanks

Comment: Personally .. I'd indeed not try to re-build native functionality custom. I can't speak for salesforce, but personally I consider it likely these functions will come to salesforce1 in the future. Salesforce delivers much faster than other platforms, so personally at times I think waiting for that is the best way to go.

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problem and ending up using Pulsar for quoting on the Mobile app.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why you chose this app? The question did ask about appexchange apps, but just the name alone isn't really a full answer.